# How to Get UserId from Branch Analytics - Branch.IO

Tags: branch.io

We have integrate Branch Analytics in our Android App (SDK App), we are passing unique userid while user signing up after installing. How we can get these Unique UserId from Branch Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

You can export raw event data logs from Branch dashboard under the Daily Exports tab. These logs would contain the user Id set by you under the user_data_developer_identity field.

The analytics on Branch dashboard show only aggregate data and user-level data such as the user Id is not available from the dashboard analytics.

If you already use some other analytics platform then you can also export your data to those platforms by using [Data Integrations](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/data-integrations).